# How to show raw pdf in web browser?

Tags: php, pdf

I am trying to show PDF that Fortnox API provides me in raw pdf format:
https://apps.fortnox.se/apidocs?pk_vid=16266b021ed6ca921683551585b13ebb#operation/getFileById

and it's format looks like:

`%PDF-1.4 %���� 1 0 obj`

what is simplest way to show that pdf in human readable pdf format?

I tried to parse it with FPDF but it convert it to some string with i am not sure what to do.

My current code that get's pdf:

```
public function showFile($access_token, $file_id)
{
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.fortnox.se/3/archive/" . $file_id,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "Authorization: Bearer " . $access_token
        ),
    ));
    // API request list all customers
    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    return $response;
}
```

I want to show that pdf on click, so i made this hook:

```
function getFile()
{
    $fileId = $_POST['fileId'];
    $fortnox = new BDCG_Fortnox();
    $fortnox_token = $fortnox->token();

    $file = $fortnox->showFile($fortnox_token, $fileId);
    
    echo $file;
    
    die();
}

add_action("wp_ajax_get_file", "getFile");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_get_file", "getFile");

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  if (jQuery('#img-qr-code')) {
    //refreshQR()
  }

  jQuery('.voucher-row').click(function () {
    console.log('test')
    const fileId = jQuery(this).data('fileid')
    getFile(fileId)
  })
})

function getFile(fileId) {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: my_ajax_object.ajax_url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      fileId: fileId,
      action: 'get_file',
    },
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data)
      displayPdf(data)
    },
    error: function (x, y, z) {
      console.error(x, y, z)
      //clearInterval(interval)
    },
  })


function displayPdf(data) {
  // Create a new PDF.js object with the received data
  const pdfData = new Uint8Array(data);
  console.log(pdfData);
  pdfjsLib.getDocument({ data }).promise.then((pdf) => {
    // Get the first page of the PDF
    pdf.getPage(1).then((page) => {
      // Set the scale of the page
      const scale = 1.5;

      // Get the viewport of the page at the given scale
      const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: scale });

      // Set the canvas element for rendering the PDF page
      const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
      canvas.height = viewport.height;
      canvas.width = viewport.width;
      document.getElementById("pdf-container").appendChild(canvas);

      // Render the PDF page on the canvas
      const renderContext = {
        canvasContext: context,
        viewport: viewport,
      };
      page.render(renderContext);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: What code do you have? What does that service return, PDF bytes or URL? If PDF bytes you need to send a PDF header so browser knows it is PDF and not HTML/plain text.

Comment: No url, only data, but i have problem because i want to show that when user click on file row, so then i pass file id to php function which calls archive endpoint and returns me raw pdf, i pass it back to javascript and i used pdfjs library to show it, but without success 
From pdfjs i am getting that it is empty 
@user3783243

Comment: Your question makes several conflicting statements. If you just want users to see the PDF in the simplest way for you, do nothing. All major browsers have a builtin PDF reader nowadays, and when they don't (e.g. mobile browsers), users are likely to have a PDF application installed.

Comment: You are mixing PHP and JS. You can't do that PHP runs first, then JS/client side actions are run. `getFile` is a PHP function?

Comment: It works when i just use file_put_contents and check that file, it is good. Better question is how to show raw pdf in pdfjs library?

Comment: `file_put_contents` is writing the PDF bytes to a file. You then have have an extension on the file that tells your system how to open it. If you rename to `.txt` and open that in your browser I suspect you'll see the same text/error.